# Reference address by name in Radare2/Cutter

Tags: ida, radare2

I have some experience with IDA and now I'm trying to use Radare2/Cutter the same way. I disassemble a DOS MZ file. I have the following:

```
;-- section.seg_000:
12: entry0 ();
0000:0000      push    ds          ; [00] -rwx section size 10784 named 
seg_000
0000:0001      xor     ax, ax
;-- di:
0000:0003      push    ax
0000:0004      mov     ah, 0x30    ; '0'
0000:0006      int     0x21
0000:0008      mov     byte cs:[0x11], al
665: fcn.0000000c ();
0000:000c      cmp     al, 2
0000:000e      jae     0x12
0000:0010      retf
0000:0011      .byte 0x00          ; RELOC 16 
0000:0012      mov     ax, 0x2a2   ; RELOC 16
```

I want to label address `0x11` as `DOSVersion` and reference it by this name instead of the offset. In IDA (Turbo Assembler syntax), I can make it look like this:

```
proc    Main far
    push    ds
    xor     ax, ax
    push    ax
    mov     ah, DOS_FN_VERSION
    int     DOS_INT
    mov     [cs:DOSVersion], al
    cmp     al, DOS_VERSION_2_0
    jnb     short ProperDosVer
    retf
DOSVersion      db 0
ProperDosVer:
    mov     ax, DSEG
```

How can I achieve the same result with Radare2/Cutter?

Answer (score 1):

In cutter you have an option under right mouse button click to set a label for a particular value.

[image]

Or you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to activate that.

From r2 you can get the same behavior by issuing a `f name = addr` command.

```
| f name 12 @ 33           set flag 'name' with length 12 at offset 33
| f name = 33              alias for 'f name @ 33' or 'f name 1 33'
```

One caveat,it has to start from `label.` to be inlined in your disassembly. If not it will show up as a comment (not sure if that can be controlled)

So in your case it would be `f label.DosVersion = 0x11`